# Reviewing closing votes - Closed for another reason

Tags: support, vote-to-close, reopen-closed

I do some closing votes reviewing once in a while and I come across questions like this one: "[Is this code an example of php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272691/is-this-code-an-example-of-php)" It was closed originally because the question was vague. However, the poster edited to question and it is clear now, but there is another problem: These questions do not belong to SO IMO.

Should I vote to reopen the question and close it for another reason (off-topic in this case) or should I click on `Leave Closed` (what I actually did)? Or is there some hidden feature which I haven't discovered yet? (or have now access to)

Comment: Any reopen vote I cast is for posts I believe should be open. Not to close it again for a different reason.

Comment: @Bart and MathieuImbert I agree with both of you, but this means we get questions which are closed by a wrong reason?

Comment: Meh, I guess that goes into my "don't care" folder. The OP can always come to Meta and ask for clarification. It wouldn't be the first time that we answer "yeah, wrong reason. Should have been this". But that's all. Even in those cases we usually don't reopen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just leave such questions closed, so voting to `Leave Closed` is the correct action here. It just requires too much coordination to re-open and close the question again.

At best, leave a comment to say why you are voting to leave it closed (*this question, although improved, is still not a fit for this site*. ... etc.)

Answer (score 3):

If the question is closed, and needs to stay closed, it should not be re-opened to be closed again with a different reason. Imagine if that would be done every time the OP edits his question to make it in shape, and he fails doing so, but changes the closing reason that applies to his question.

Just leave a comment saying that the question is not still in shape to be re-opened, and explain why the question is not going to be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a question that can be answered by a simple *Yes* or *No* is not a real question. Don't reopen it.

In general, if a question is not good enough to be reopened, don't reopen it. Whatever the original reason was to close it, it won't benefit anyone to reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicates may be an exception since they have some special logic and are arguably more okay, but in general it doesn't really matter if you're too localized, NARQ, etc.  "Closed means closed" is a more important business rule and the reason is more of an add-on (that's helpful in sorting review queues and giving a helpful message as to why it was closed.)

There is obviously big overlap between NC/NARQ/localized, so I wouldn't heed much which is picked.