# Upvote comments in 'Reopen votes' queue

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-reopen, comment-voting

We can upvote comments in some review queue's, but not in the 'Reopen votes' queue.

I think we should also enable this in this queue, because a question can be revisited, but still wrong. As told in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170946/reviewing-closing-votes-closed-for-another-reason) it's good to add a comment which describes why it still cannot be reopened. Sometimes, another users already posted such a comment. Instead of adding 2 duplicate comments, I'd like to upvote that comment.

Comment: A less specific but highly related request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146783/allow-voting-on-comments-from-review-interface

Comment: I've no idea why users can't do this as it seems logical and valuable.

Answer (score 6):

I agree; but I think it should be included in the close votes queue as well for the same reasons.

When reviewing those queues without this ability I often come across comments that I would like to vote up. In the Reopen and Close queues this is, I think, especially important as people often comment as to why they are voting in the way that they are.

You can signal agreement with someone's reasoning for voting to reopen, without creating additional noise, by voting up their comment. This helps the reasoning for the vote to stand out and provides a different viewpoint to the original closers. The converse is partially true in the Close queue; a user may well have stated why they do not believe a question should be closed. If you agree with their reasoning then being able to vote up the comment makes it more noticeable to potential close voters.

Answer (score 2):

It would be useful to see the comments in all of the queues, not only so you could upvote them, but also they might explain some things.  I often have to click into the question to see if there are any comments to get information to make decisions.

Answer (score 2):

I've just come across this question whilst considering writing exactly the same thing.

I completely agree as I'd like to:

- Upvote useful, constructive comments
- Flag useless/offensive comments

Example:

[image]

As I understand it, some queues consider either an upvote and/or comment as a review, but that needn't be the case for all queues. It's also rather ironic that a reviewer can ADD a comment, but not upvote/flag others.